# How do i get all column values of aspnetusers table right after registering in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, asp.net-core-identity

i am facing this issue where i have an identity column in aspnetuser table and i need to get the value of this db generated identity column value right after registration i am using these lines of code

```
  var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email };
                    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password); 

 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        [NotMapped]
        public int? U_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

i have tried below lines but some of them returns null and some only returns the data which is either entered by user like username and password and email and fields generated by identity like normalized email etc but i am unable to get U_ID column it remains null

```
 ApplicationUser usersss = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
                        //string message = "Hello " + user.UserName;


                        var usernames = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

                        var userEmail = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name); // will give the user's Email

                        var user2 = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
                        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                        HttpContext.User = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
                        ApplicationUser userjsss = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

                        var userIds = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);


                        var userv = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
```

it is very crucial to get this U_ID column value and store in an inmemory claim as this will be needed throughout the app unless user logs out

Comment: what is `U_ID`? it's not mapped so it will not be auto-filled by efcore by any means.

Comment: @KingKing U_ID is a column that has one to one relationship with another table named Users 
now the issue is that its AutoIncremented in the Db table as  i have made it Identity insert autoincrement on..But once data is inserted i am unable to get this column value

Comment: but why do you apply this `[NotMapped]` on it? it means it's not part of your EFCore models.

Comment: @KingKing because its value is being generated by database and if i remove [NotMapped] then i will get exception of adding value in identity column
i can simply remove this U_ID property from ApplicationUser class as its value is generated by Db...but its value is important that i need to get from db after registration is done with CreateAsync

Comment: @KingKing so this is what all i needed on my U_ID field         [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
instead of [NotMapped] as this was causing the EFCore not to map it and hence was returning NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer i was using [NotMapped] attribute which was not mapping efcore model and hence i was getting null in U_ID column all i had to do was to remove `[NotMapped]` and use             `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`
instead

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        //[NotMapped]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int? U_ID { get; set; }
    }
```